# ZFS pool degraded with faulted disk, export and replace not working

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, zpool

I run into troubles after trying to add more disks to my Ubuntu server device. While being a total beginner I powered the server off, added two more disks and restarted the system only to find one of the disks in the existing mirror "FAULTED".

```
matsojala@amatson:~$ zpool status -v
  pool: tank
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
        invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
        functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 21h20m with 0 errors on Fri Feb  8 14:15:04 2019
config:

        NAME                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                DEGRADED     0     0     0
            sdb                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            12086301109920570165  FAULTED      0     0     0  was /dev/sdb1

errors: No known data errors
```

I tried to export and import based on this answer ([ZFS pool degraded on reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/935123/zfs-pool-degraded-on-reboot?newreg=00c320f2930e4bd5b6e6403cc071b435)) but exporting fails

```
matsojala@amatson:~$ sudo zpool export -f tank
umount: /tank: target is busy.
cannot unmount '/tank': umount failed
```

I'm not sure which way I should try to replace the disk as the disk on the system is "part of active pool".

```
matsojala@amatson:~$ sudo zpool replace -f tank 12086301109920570165 sdc1
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/sdc1 is part of active pool 'tank'
```

Tried this too.

```
matsojala@amatson:~$ sudo zpool replace tank sdb
/dev/sdb is in use and contains a unknown filesystem.
```

Any help? The disk was fully working before powering off, it is in the system named as /dev/sdc1 with ID "12086301109920570165". What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've been using names like `/dev/sda` to reference disks. That's generally not a good idea, because if your disks get assigned different names after a reboot or an unplug-replug cycle, then ZFS can get confused. Instead, you should create your pool using the device files in `/dev/disk/by-id/`, `.../by-uuid/`, or `.../by-label/`.

In your case, I'm not totally certain, but it kind of looks like `/dev/sdb1` got relabeled to `/dev/sdc1` after reboot, which is why `/dev/sdc1` looks like it's part of the pool even though it doesn't appear in `zpool status`. You could try to fix it by unplugging the extra disks you added -- that would probably allow the labels to go back to how they were originally -- and then doing an `export` followed by `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id tank`, to force ZFS to relabel the pool based on the `by-id` disk names.

If the export doesn't work because it's busy, make sure no process is accessing files on the pool and try again. I am not a Linux user, but it appears there is also some configuration file you can use to help you do this during reboot: [this post on Github](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/3043) suggests setting `USE_DISK_BY_ID='yes'` in `/etc/default/zfs` to force it during reboot. Worst case you can set that and reboot -- reboot automatically runs export / import.

That said, if you want to go through with replacing the disk anyway, the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbcet/index.html) explain the "replace one faulted disk of a mirror" use case pretty well. (Just ignore the Solaris-specific instructions about unconfiguring the disk with `cfgadm`.) I think the main steps you missed were running `zpool offline tank <faulted disk>` before running `zpool replace tank <new disk>`.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what happened, suddenly export worked and once I figured I had to sudo the import the pool accepted both disks and started resilvering process. I used the by-id import now that I know more about what to do. I guess some processes had stopped to make the export happen, the problem was that I wasn't sure how to find and kill those processes. Hopefully the errors disappear after resilvering.